# Centre environment at different spots on different pages

Tags: texstudio

I'm a bit ignorant when it comes to LaTeX so forgive me if I've just done something really stupid. I've been running into general formatting issues when using the `book` class. The `center` environment appears to have a different 'centre' depending on what page it is on (odd or even page number). Additionally, it's writing contents at the top of most pages and the table of contents isn't really showing up.

I put example code of the problem below. I'm not sure how to attach the generated PDF but I would assume one could just copy and paste the code. Any help would be really appreciated. I'm using TeXstudio to compile.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}  %Settings
\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt             
\raggedright                            

\title{\bf Random Title}    %Info   
\author{Some Author}              
\date{\today}                           

\begin{document}                       
\frontmatter        %Starts roman page numerals                           
\maketitle          %Tittle page
\tableofcontents    %Table of Contents (doesn't print?)
\mainmatter         %Start regular numbers
\part{A Part}                   
\chapter{A chapter}                
A bunch of random text.\\
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\begin{center}
Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\
Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\
Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\
Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\
Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\
Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\Some text\\
\end{center}
\chapter{another chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We all began learning the basics. The first thing is that using `\chapter*{}` will suppress it from showing in the table of contents, use `\chapter{}` instead (the same thing goes for `\section`, `\subsection`, etc). In terms of the centering of the text, it is already centered with respect to the page. I truly recommend you to add `\usepackage{showframe}` right after `\documentclass[11pt]{book}` to see what is going on. This package will draw the margins on page. If you want the text to be centered on even and odd pages, they will not be centered with respect to the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you additionally load `showframe, you can see your text is centred w.r.t. the margins on all pages. You seem to forget that the inner and the outer margins are not equal, in traditional typography, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Forgot it was supposed to be printed back to back and thus the 'off-centre' text was not off centre at all. I was using chapter* to suppress it from showing the chapter # before displaying the chapter. Is there a way to suppress the header above the chapter title but not suppress it in the table of contents? I can't seem to find one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you call the ‘header’?  Normally, the first page of a chapter uses the `plain` page style, so there's no header, and only a footer with the page number (centred).

Comment: I mean how it displays Chapter 1 then below that the chapter name. With chapter* it just displays the chapter name. I shouldn't have used the term header; that just obfuscates the matter.

Comment: The `center` is with respect to the available text area provided by the document class.  As you note, the `book` class skews its text area right and left on even and odd pages.  It sounds to me that what you are really saying is that you don't like a document class that has such a skew.